# Package webdatabase in phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova

Phonegap storage documentation [speaks](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494756/Adding-SQL-Database-support-to-your-iPhone-App) only [about](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) how data can be added to the app via code. I want to push a compiled database (say Directory of phone numbers) to the PhoneGap app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot push a compiled DB.

What you can do is to include the content of this database as a SQL file in your app, load it in ajax and use phonegap [executeSql](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction) function to populate the DB.

This would of course only need to run once.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking too. But not as Ajax, but to have the entire SQL dump. Was looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: Since the implementation of WebSQL (or its version) may vary from browser to browser, this is the most elegant solution. Having a compiled DB would garantee some compatibility troubles.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just export the DB to a text format (CSV or JSON), and depending on the size and how/what you are querying, either load it in memory or add it to the localStorage (or SQL) in the target PhoneGap framework...

The only other way I see this happening is by using [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) - a NOSQL DB that has support for Android/iOS/PhoneGap - which can also synchronize a local DB with a remote one (all magic!) thus allowing your remote phone numbers to change and still to be updated (incremental) at your client.

Hope this helps